# ¿Cómo parar una simulación en simpy mediante una entrada por teclado?

Tags: python

Quiero que mi simulación en tiempo real sea infinita excepto si hay alguna entrada por teclado. En ese caso pararía la simulación e imprimiría "Se ha parado la simulación", por lo que no me vale con ctrl+C.

De la forma en la que tengo el código no me deja introducir nada en el teclado mientras se está llevando a cabo la simulación, y si lo hago mediante bloques if... else... no ejecuta la simulación esperando a que introduzca algo por el teclado.

El código es el siguiente:

```
import simpy as sp

def prueba():
    try:
        while True:
                print ("bien")
                yield env.timeout(1)
        
    except input():
        print ("se ha parado la simulación")
        
env = sp.RealtimeEnvironment(factor=1, strict=True)
env.process(prueba())
env.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

El módulo `msvcrt`, que es un modulo para Windows (el cual asumo que es tu sistema operativo), tiene una función llamada `kbhit`, cuyo proposito es devolver True cuando hay una pulsación de tecla esperando a ser leida. Por ejemplo si presionas F1 y pasan 10 segundos, esta función devolverá True.

Podemos usar esta función a nuestro favor y hacer que cuando el usuario presionó una tecla, la simulación acabe.

```
import simpy as sp
import msvcrt

def prueba():
    # Leo cualquier pulsación de tecla anterior al inicio de la simulación.
    # Esto tiene de proposito evitar la posibilidad de que el usuario presione una tecla antes del inicio de la simulación y por lo tanto esta no se ejecute.
    while msvcrt.kbhit():
        msvcrt.getch()
    
    while True:
        # Si hay una pulsación de tecla esperando a ser leida
        # rompo el bucle while, acabando con la simulación.
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            break

        print("bien")
        yield env.timeout(1)

    # Si sale del bucle while, es que la simulación terminó, 
    # por lo que imprimo el mensaje correspondiente.
    print("Se ha parado la simulación.")
        
env = sp.RealtimeEnvironment(factor=1, strict=True)
env.process(prueba())
env.run()
```

*Nota*: Hice este código asumiendo que la simulación NUNCA será reiniciada una vez el usuario presione una tecla.